# How to call _count from elasticsearch-rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rails

As the title says, I want to make the following query from rails with the `elasticsearch-rails` gem.

```
curl -XGET "localhost:9200/my_index/_count?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "my_field": 12
    }
  }
}
'
```

I have tried this:

```
MyModel.search("cats", search_type: 'count').results.total
```

and I get
`Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest ([400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"No search type for [count]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"No search type for [count]"},"status":400})`

The `curl` call works fine from the console.

Despite some people thinking that `count` has been deprecated the Count API seems alive and well in ES 7.7 - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html